# Dynamic hazard (logic)

Tags: logic

I'm self studying logic and math in my free time, and I'd like to ask for help. I also do not know how to format the maths expressions, so sorry for that. But a single quote after a capital letter means a boolean variable is in complement/negated form. A plus sign is the OR operation, the lack of operator symbol is AND operation. SOP stands for DNF, POS stands for CNF.

Currently I have a hard time understanding dynamic hazards in logic. In a video, someone introduced this the following way with Karnaugh map. Suppose, we have three functions, $F$, $F_1$ and $F_2$, where $F$ is final output and equals to $F_1 F_2$.

Unfortunately he did not wrote boolean expressions and that confuses me a lot regarding $F_2$, as I totally lost it during the visual approach. I translated his Karnaugh maps to:

$F_1=A’C’+BC$, $F_2=A’B’+BC$. $F_1$ has static hazard $A’B$ (as a redundant grouping of minterms $m_2m_3$).
However, he was not using the minterms ($1$s) in $F_2$ for the hazard, but the Maxterms ($0$s). So he showed, that in $F_2$ there is a static hazard $(A’+C’)$, as Maxterms $M_4$ and $M_6$ are not "grouped".

Now I've seen that dynamic hazards can be either be in the form of $X(X+X’)$ or $XX’+X$ for $0/1$ hazards respectively. However I do not understand how to write down the boolean form of the F function ($F_1 F_2$) so I could look for the above hazard forms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: It would help if you could define what a (dynamic) hazard is, as I don't think people on this site are familiar with this. This question might be more suitable for [electrical engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Well actually I now understand,

I can write the $F$ function as $F=(A’C’+BC)(A’+B)(B’+C)$. Then I look for ways to reduce this to $F = (1C’+1C)(1)(0+C) = (C’+C)(C)$, as only C can cause a dynamic hazard.
To get the reduced form, $A$ must be $0$ and $B$ must be $1$.

To suppress the dynamic hazard, I need to test them vs the $(C’+C)$ part (without changing the function), so: $F=(A’C’+BC+A’B)(A’+B)(B’+C)$.